# Python CX Oracle - databaserror dbapi - 1407

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have a Python connection issue using `cx-Oracle` - I am unable to connect to the database.

I need to install the Oracle client at the machine in offline mode, so I have unzipped the source file.

I have unzipped the 64 bit version of the Oracle client tool and saved in the `opt` folder in linux.

My machine has an updated version of the `libaio` package.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is also set and points to the `opt` folder client files.

But I still get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check from python: 
(Your version may be other than 11.2).

print(os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"])

There should be something as:

/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib

And check that exists file /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so